# Faster the nested for loops

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-science, kaggle

In kaggle competition, I developed a new score method. However, to do that, need to match some words in text and some words from vocab. To create vocab, I used

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, lowercase=False)
vectorizer.fit(disaster_tweets)
disaster_voc = vectorizer.vocabulary_
vectorizer.fit(non_disaster_tweets)
non_disaster_voc = vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

Then, I substract the same word counts from another with some loop. It was fast. However this line of code is super slow. This is the substraction code:

```
for  key_1 in list(disaster_voc):
    for key_2 in list(non_disaster_voc):
        if key_1.lower() == key_2.lower():
            disaster_voc[key_1] = disaster_voc[key_1] - non_disaster_voc[key_2]
```

Then the real part is matching the vocabulary words with words in tweets for every tweet. This is the code:

```
score_train = []
for i in range(len(train['text'].values)):
    score = 0
    for  key_1 in list(disaster_voc):
        for word in word_tokenize(train['text'].values[i]):
            if word.lower() == key_1.lower():
                if disaster_voc[key_1] >= 0:
                    score += disaster_voc[key_1]

    score_train.append(score)
    print(score)
```

I get tweets from text column, than if it in tweets and has a positive score, I add up it to score. Totally it collects total score in 1-2 seconds and for 7000-8000 rows, it takes hours,days...

If you can find total fast way or faster loop advice please help. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to want to ignore case when counting words. Why do you set `lowercase=False` in your `CountVectorizer`?

Comment: I missed that. keys are not lowered, I handle them in loop. The run speed does not effected by it so much. Last function takes too much time.

Comment: It will probably take a lot of time out of your loops if you don't have to lowercase the keys first. Also, to find the intersection between two dicts, use set arithmetics `for common_key in set(disaster_voc) & set(non_disaster_voc):` (but of course this only works when the keys are lowercase to begin with).

Comment: You can apply set arithmetics in the same way to your last code snippet and get rid of some of those loops.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for help.